# MS Access: Truncate Calculate Fields

Tags: ms-access, module, expression, truncate, calculated-field

I am doing a migration of calculated data from Excel to Access and realized that Access does not have the Truncate function. I need the Truncate function to drop numbers to 2 decimal places, for e.g. 10.32790 to 10.32.

I created the module as specified here: http://www.anysitesupport.com/access-truncate-function/

However, I tried using the Trunc() function in the Calculated Field in my table (via expression builder) and was told that I could not do that to a calculated field. What is the proper way to make us of the newly created module?

Comment: That's not really truncation; it's rounding (from five decimal places to two). You may have better luck searching for *Access Round function*.

Comment: You don't want to round 10.32790 to 10.33? You truly want to truncate?

Comment: You're using a calculated field... do you really want to truncate the number, or do you just want to only display two decimal digits? Those are two completely separate problems.

Comment: If you are doing a lot of migration, you may benefit from my rounding functions: [Rounding values up, down, by 4/5, or to significant figures](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/20299/Rounding-values-up-down-by-4-5-or-to-significant-figures.html)

Comment: I truly want to truncate. I do not want to do a rounding!

Answer (score 1):

You can just use built-in functions in calculated fields. One more argument not to use them. Build a query with an additional field where the calculation is done:

`SELECT myFieldA, myFieldB, Trunc(myFieldToBeTruncated, 2) as myTruncedField FROM myTable`.

If it has to be a calculated field, you have to rebuild the function Trunc in the calculated field `Fix([myFieldToBeTruncated] * 100) / 100`

Comment: True. Refrain from using calculated fields in tables.

Comment: For me to rebuild the function in the calculated field, what is it that I have to do? Write a new module and edit the expression builder for a specific build in the table? Really sorry about this, I do not know where to put it!

Comment: Just put `Fix([myFieldToBeTruncated] * 100) / 100` in the calc field where `myFieldToBeTruncated` is the name of the column with the not truncated data. But this is not recommended. Do you just want to import the data? Then update the column after import. If you want the full data in table but just show it truncated, add a field with the `Trunc()`function in a query as advised.